# How to get bind a (WPF or Infragistics) DataGrid to a List<List<string>> or List<string[]>?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, mvvm

I need to bind a collection of strings inside a collection of strings to a DataGrid (Infragistics).

However, when I bind it like this:

```
<DataPresenter:XamDataGrid x:Name="xamDataGrid" DataSource="{Binding TheCollection}">
```

to either this:

```
public List<string[]> TheCollection
```

or this:

```
public List<List<string>> TheCollection
```

I get this:

[image]

**What kind of .NET types do I need to use so that it displays this collection within a collection as a grid**, i.e. like this:

```
bank11  1111111
bank12  2222222
```

I can't use custom objects since this is being used by a module that can't have any references to other modules and has to accept simple .NET types.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a [`Dictionary<String,String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).